# Sort groupby pandas output by Month name and year

Tags: python, pandas, calendar

**df**

```
order_date    Month Name   Year   Days  Data
2015-12-20     Dec         2014    1     3
2016-1-21      Jan         2014    2     3
2015-08-20     Aug         2015    1     1 
2016-04-12     Apr         2016    4     1

and so on
```

**Code:**

```
df = df.groupby(["Year", "Month Name"], as_index=False)["days"].agg(['min', 
'mean'])
df3 = (df.groupby(["Year", "Month Name"], as_index=False) 
["Data"].agg(['count']))
merged_df=pd.merge(df3, df, on=['Year','Month Name'])
```

I have a groupby output as below

```
                    Min Mean    Count
Year    Month Name                  
2015    Aug          2    11      200
        Dec          5    13      130
        Feb          3    15      100
        Jan          4    20      123
        May          1    21      342
        Nov          2    12      234
 2016   Apr          1    10      200
        Dec          2    12      120
        Feb          2    13      200
        Jan          2    24      200
        Sep          1    25      220
```

**Issue:**

Basically **I am getting output of groupby sorted by Month Name starting from A to Z**, So I am getting April, August, December, Feb etc......rather than Jan, Feb ....till Dec etc. **How to get output sorted by Month number.**

I **need output like 2016, Jan, Feb ....Dec then 2017, Jan , Feb, Mar till Dec**

Please help if there is merging of 2 dfs. I have just presented a simplified code here(real code is different, I need to merge both and then only I can work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Your solution should be changed:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["Year", "Month Name"], as_index=False)["Days"].agg(['min', 'mean'])
df3 = df.groupby(["Year", "Month Name"], as_index=False)["Data"].agg(['count'])
merged_df=pd.merge(df3, df1, on=['Year','Month Name']).reset_index()

cats = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
merged_df['Month Name'] = pd.Categorical(merged_df['Month Name'],categories=cats, ordered=True)

merged_df = merged_df.sort_values(["Year", "Month Name"])
print (merged_df)
   Year Month Name  count  min  mean
1  2014        Jan      1    2     2
0  2014        Dec      1    1     1
2  2015        Aug      1    1     1
3  2016        Apr      1    4     4
```

Or:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(["Year", "Month Name"])
         .agg(min_days=("Days", 'min'),
              avg_days=("Days", 'mean'),
              count = ('Data', 'count'))
         .reset_index())

cats = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
df1['Month Name'] = pd.Categorical(df1['Month Name'], categories=cats, ordered=True)

df1 = df1.sort_values(["Year", "Month Name"])
print (df1)
   Year Month Name  min_days  avg_days  count
1  2014        Jan         2         2      1
0  2014        Dec         1         1      1
2  2015        Aug         1         1      1
3  2016        Apr         4         4      1
```

Last solution with `MultiIndex` and no categoricals, solution create helper dates column and sorting by it:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(["Year", "Month Name"])
         .agg(min_days=("Days", 'min'),
              avg_days=("Days", 'mean'),
              count = ('Data', 'count'))
        )


df1['dates'] = pd.to_datetime([f'{y}{m}' for y, m in df1.index], format='%Y%b')
df1 = df1.sort_values('dates')
print (df1)
                 min_days  avg_days  count      dates
Year Month Name                                      
2014 Jan                2         2      1 2014-01-01
     Dec                1         1      1 2014-12-01
2015 Aug                1         1      1 2015-08-01
2016 Apr                4         4      1 2016-04-01
```

Comment: Please help if 2 dataframes are being merged

Comment: No the mean , mean are on one dataframe and count are on another dataframe

Comment: days and Data column are different. Please check i have changed the input'

Comment: min, mean are on days column and count is on data column

Comment: Thanks the solution works perfectly, but month name and year are not reflecting

Comment: df1 = (df.groupby(["Year", "Month Name"], as_index=False, sort=False)
         .agg(min_days=("days", 'min')
              avg_days=("days", 'mean')
              count = ('Data', 'count')))

Comment: I used this code. Everything is working. I just need month name and year too

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - Sorry, now tested and a bit changed solutions - used only working solutions.

Comment: Hi your solution worked perfectly. However my index column values are not starting from 0, 1,2 etc instead they are random like 4,1,5,3,2,0 etc. Can you help how to make sure I have index values from 0,1,2 etc

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - Only add this line of code `df1 = df.reset_index(drop=True)` for convert to default index.

Answer (score 3):

Simply tell groupby you don't want it to sort group keys (by default, that's what it does - see [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html))

```
df.groupby(["Year", "Month Name"], as_index=False, sort=False)["Days"].agg(
    ["min", "mean"]
)
```

NOTE: you should make sure your `df` is sorted before applying groupby

Comment: Please help if 2 dataframes are being merged. How to work out then'

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to sort by month number and return sorted month names for `level=1` of multiindex taking `merged_df` as the input:

```
import calendar
d={i:e for e,i in enumerate([*calendar.month_abbr])}
#for full month name use :-> d={i:e for e,i in enumerate([*calendar.month_name])} 

merged_df.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(sorted(merged_df.index,key=lambda x: d.get(x[1])))
merged_df = merged_df.sort_index(level=0)
```

---

```
print(merged_df)
                 count  min  mean
Year Month Name                  
2014 Jan             1    2     2
     Dec             1    1     1
2015 Aug             1    1     1
2016 Apr             1    4     4
```

Comment: NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented

---> 32     merged_df.reindex(idx[np.argsort(idx.map(d))],level=1)

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor ahh i see , duplicate index is causing this , let me check if i can come up with something

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor can you check now please

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor are you getting any error? this should work IMO. this solution is sorting the multiindex level1 based on the month number. do you have a `Jan` or `January` in the index (like full month name v/s abbreviated month names) ?